# Paypal form return value

Tags: paypal

I'm fighting against Paypal.

I'm trying to use 'return' variable but for some reason it did not work.

The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B) says:

`return`
The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser after they complete their payments. For example, specify a URL on your site that displays a "Thank you for your payment" page.
Default – PayPal redirects the browser to a PayPal webpage.

`rm`
Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the URL specified by the return variable.
Allowable values are:
0 – all shopping cart payments use the GET method
1 – the buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but no payment variables are included
2 – the buyer's browser is redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment variables are included

So I decide add to my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.site.com/payment_confirm.php" />  
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.site.com/back" />  
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
```

But for some reason at the end of the payment nothing happens.
So I try to search on google why this could be and some people wrote to active the automatic redirect to a page at the end of transaction from profile.

So I went in the profile page and setted up the auto return to
    www.site.com/
When I tryed again after the transaction paypal return me in the profile url and not in the url written in the form AND there are some data in the URL so the form hasn't use the POST method.

My ideas is over. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When you enabled Auto-Return did you also turn on Payment Data Transfer (PDT)? Doing that makes it so all the information returned to your site is a GET regardless of the "rm" value.